# getText() returns empty string (android studio)

Tags: java, android

I have a little question here about android development.

I already searched on internet, but i still can't find the solution.

---

I want to `getText()` from a view, but it just returns an empty ("") string. 
Here's my .java code:

```
    public void kotakCentang(View view) 
    {
          RelativeLayout vwParentRow = (RelativeLayout)view.getParent();
          TextView id_test = (TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(0);
          TextView nama_test = (TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(1);
          tugas_status = (TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(5);
          tanggalKasih = (EditText)vwParentRow.getChildAt(6);
          tanggalKumpul = (EditText)vwParentRow.getChildAt(8);
          waktuKasih = (EditText)vwParentRow.getChildAt(7);
          waktuKumpul = (EditText)vwParentRow.getChildAt(9);
          tugasKompleksitas = (EditText)vwParentRow.getChildAt(10);
          Tugas tugas = new Tugas();
          TugasRepo tugass = new TugasRepo(this);
          tugas.nama = nama_test.getText().toString();
          tugas.waktuDikasih = waktuKasih.getText().toString();
          tugas.waktuDikumpul = waktuKumpul.getText().toString();
          tugas.tanggalDikasih = tanggalKasih.getText().toString();
          tugas.tanggalDikumpul = tanggalKumpul.getText().toString();
          tugas.kompleksitas=Integer.parseInt(tugasKompleksitas.getText().toString());
          tugasKompleksitas.getText().toString();

    }
```

The `getText()` which returns empty string is just the `tugas.waktuDikasih`, and `tugas.waktuDikumpul` .

Thank you for your help.

----- UPDATE XML ----
here's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tugas_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/judul_tugas"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="judul tugas"
        android:id="@+id/tugas_judul"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tugas_id"
        />

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/status_kerja"
        android:checked="false"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tugas_judul"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="kotakCentang"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_below="@+id/status_kerja"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2">
    </View>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Detil"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/status_kerja"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:onClick="detilTugas"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="status"
        android:id="@+id/status_tugas"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tugas_judul"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tugas_id" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/tanggal_diberikan"
        android:text="Tanggal Diberikan"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/waktu_diberikan"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tanggal_diberikan"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tanggal_diberikan"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tanggal_diberikan"
        android:text="Waktu diberikan"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="date"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/tanggal_kumpul"
        android:text="Tanggal dikumpulkan"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tugas_judul"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/waktu_diberikan"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/waktu_diberikan"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/waktu_dikumpulkan"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tanggal_kumpul"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tanggal_kumpul"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tanggal_kumpul"
        android:text="Waktu dikumpulkan"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/isi_kompleksitas"
        android:text="Kompleksitas"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:editable="false"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <!--<TextView-->
    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--android:text="id_tugas"-->
    <!--android:id="@+id/tugas_id"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/status_kerja"-->
    <!--android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tugas_judul"-->
    <!--android:layout_marginEnd="117dp" />-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: did you input some value to edittext?

Comment: @PhanVănLinh yes, i put a value in it.

Comment: only 2 edittext return "", another edittext return value, right?
can you post your xml?

Comment: Why you have double close paranthesis in last two lines `toString())`

Comment: @PhanVănLinh yes, i already update the question.

Comment: @Clairvoyant oh, i just misstype there, thank you.

Comment: Both of those `EditText` views are marked as `GONE` in the XML. Are you making them visible programmatically?

Comment: @DavidWasser Yes sir, i just want to take the value from those view, to pass to another variable.

Comment: All of your `View`s should have an `id`. To be sure that you are actually accessing the `View`s you think you are, you should try using `findViewById()` instead of `getChildAt()`. You might find your problem easier that way.